# Periodic freezes - possibly related to CoreAnimation?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, performance, logs

For many months, I have experienced occasional lockups on my Macbook Pro 8,2 running OSX 10.9.2. Actually, I had what I assume was a related problem in 10.8. I have the 2.3GHz Core i7 processor, 8GB of RAM, and a Samsung 840 Pro SSD. I've begun to seriously try to debug this problem, which happens maybe once or twice per week (I'm a heavy user, so this is relatively infrequent), as my AppleCare ends in a few months.

The freezes are sudden and I don't notice they have happened until I try to use the trackpad. All graphics stay the same, but nothing else works. I can't Cmd+Tab. Any video or audio that was playing stop. To reboot, I have to hold down the power button.

I've tried the usual maintenance things:

- I've cleaned and rebuilt thoroughly with ONYX.
- I've updated Firefox, Dropbox, and Jottacloud to the latest versions.
- I've stayed on top of all OSX updates.
- I ran a full memory test.
- I ran CINEBENCH benchmarks with no problems.

I'm now looking in the logs for help. Here is what I found today after a freeze:

```
18/03/14 11:36:19,208 Java Updater[11210]: Hostname check passed. Valid Oracle hostname
18/03/14 11:38:05,564 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:40:00,689 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:40:54,712 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:43:08,324 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:46:45,450 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:52:52,620 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:55:13,099 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:57:36,335 WindowServer[95]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [128840588218023]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
18/03/14 11:57:36,336 WindowServer[95]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
18/03/14 11:57:47,460 loginwindow[64]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
18/03/14 11:58:30,035 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 11:59:26,824 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Killing auth hosts
18/03/14 11:59:26,824 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100121 destroyed
18/03/14 11:59:26,826 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100123 created
18/03/14 11:59:27,002 Wunderlist[11280]: ERROR: unable to get the receiver data from the DB!
18/03/14 12:00:13,304 Wunderlist[11280]: ERROR: purgeItemFromFileSystemStore - unlink of file (null) failed Errno=14.
18/03/14 12:02:15,409 netbiosd[10675]: name servers down?
18/03/14 12:02:58,000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1395140578 0
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl". Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.bookstore" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 syslogd[18]: Configuration Notice: ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages. Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 kernel[0]: PMAP: PCID enabled
18/03/14 12:03:01,000 kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64
```

I assume that the netbiosd warnings relate to me blocking traffic with Little Snitch. I doubt that would cause a freeze (though let me know if I'm wrong). I'm currently suspicious of the CoreAnimation warnings. I've noticed these before preceding crashes, though sometimes they seem to be in the logs even when no crash has occurred. Is it possible that this is causing my problems? If so, what is CoreAnimation and how can I fix it?

Note that I am on my third SSD in this system, and (while I've had warranty replacements) I've always suspected that something about this system is frying them because both have died right after a freeze. Right now I'm ignoring that suspicion and trying to follow the logs in a systematic manner, but if you think these SSD issues may be indicative of something, please let me know.

**Update:** I just had another crash and found the following information in my console. I wonder what this "previous shutdown cause" part is telling us.

```
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: AGC: 3.4.35, HW version=1.9.23, flags:0, features:20600
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key LsNM (kSMCKeyNotFound)
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR LsNM kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcGetLightshowVers ERROR: smcReadKey LsNM failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcPublishLightshowVersion ERROR: smcGetLightshowVers failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: smcPublishLightshowVersion failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: 3
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: MMIO regMap == NULL - fall back to old SMC mode
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
03/04/14 11:08:33,000 kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x821A FirmwareVersion - 0x0042
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you expand the Console log to 20-30 lines some before some after the freeze.

Comment: Did you check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544207/how-to-avoid-coreanimation-warning-deleted-thread-with-uncommitted-catransactio

Comment: I see that other answer is related, though I'm not developing my own app and I don't have access to the code. I'm currently wearing the hat of the end user and wondering how I can trace down which of my apps are causing the problem.

I'll expand my log snippet.

Comment: I just added some additional log output, though many lines are basically the same so hopefully it is useful. There is a lot more obviously that happened during the boot.

Comment: none shows the fatal error, indicating system freeze? but there is a log kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms not sure what it means, lets check.

Comment: The lines I show should be everything that happened in the 25 minutes before the freeze. I guess maybe whatever crashed did it so suddenly that it didn't log about it. Note that this is the "All messages" section in the console. Let me know if I should be looking elsewhere, in an individual file perhaps.

Comment: Another minor note: There are a couple errors from Wunderlist. This was only installed very recently and the crashes predate this app. So while Wunderlist could have caused this crash, it isn't the underlying culprit.